# NextJS Hosting Serverless-Framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, amazon-cloudfront, serverless, cloudflare

Currently I'm hosting my website on AWS using the [serverless-nextjs](https://github.com/serverless-nextjs/serverless-next.js). My website is a simple demo that uses some SSG,ISR and SSR. I would like my pages that are built with SSG and ISR to be distributed to a CDN, and that's what serverless framework helps with but they are using cloudfront for this.

Cloudfront has an expensive pricing on bandwith ranging from lowest 0.085/GB, not to mention they charge for requests aswell. And apparently Cloudflare provide these features for free.

So my question is, is it possible to move away from Cloudfront to Cloudflare while still using the serverless-nextjs and still using the normal nextjs features (ISR,SSR..)? If so, how would I go about doing the switch? if not, what are other viable solutions?

I'm expecting my main website to be using alot of bandwith due to many visitors, so this is concerning me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using AWS Amplify to host next.js apps. its pricing is based on requests I believe.

> to deploy a Next.js app using Amplify Hosting. Amplify supports the
> hosting of static apps and apps with dynamic server-side rendered
> routes (SSR).

You can reduce the bandwidth by setting up a free Cloudflare plan on top of your AWS Amplify

https://docs.amplify.aws/guides/hosting/nextjs/q/platform/js/

for Pricing:

https://aws.amazon.com/amplify/pricing/

Comment: AWS Amplify costs actually even more, 0.15$/gb bandwith. Also the free tier on Cloudfront is more rewarding than the one that is offered on Amplify.

Comment: but it does not charge on # of requests

Comment: also as mentioned in the answer you can use the cloudflare free plan on top of aws amplify to reduce cost

Comment: You're right but sadly the biggest costs are usually coming from the bandwidth itself. That is why I'm looking for a way that could help me move away from Cloudfront to Cloudflare

Comment: what about Cloudflare free plan on top of AWS amplify

Comment: That sounds interesting, how would I go about implementing this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240932/discussion-between-renewablezip-and-aws-ps).

Comment: I haven't heard back from you , of this solution turned out to be good one, please mark the answer as approved